# How to stop mobile web page draggable horizontally?

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a website(www.damabbs.com) using Bootstrap. The problem is the webpage is draggable horizontally when user wants to scroll down using iPhone safari. It is very annoying.

I have checked with bootstrap website. It works fine. It can only be draggable vertically.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that code in `base.css` line 34

```
@media ( max-width : 766px) {
body {
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 5px !important;
padding-right: 5px !important;
}
```

to

```
@media ( max-width : 766px) {
body {
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 10px !important;
padding-right: 10px !important;
}
```